# How to Bypass robot check without rotating my IP?

Tags: adobe

I cannot offord IP rotation as it is very costly, is there any way to bypass the captcha without rotating the IP with using only the current IP?

Comment: it won't be possible in whatsapp & in paytm also... i tried it in zomato ...

Comment: Having a robot go where robots *shall not* go is unethical where not strictly illegal.

Comment: Hi, FYI, there are IP rotations options which are free or "almost" free. FreeProxies is completely free and Amazon API Gateway is free for the first million requests per region, which means that for most use cases this should be completely free.
If that sounds relevant, you may follow my technical guidelines at https://sgino209.medium.com/ip-rotation-with-python-c8033a079f4d.